# How do make regex match all or nothing

Tags: c#, regex

I want a RegEx to match the string that composes a valid IP, colon, and port. If the string contains a valid IP and invalid port # or vice-versa, I want it to match nothing at all. I'm implementing this in a C# app.

To do this, I'm trying to integrate the following from [How to Find or Validate an IP Address](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
```

with the following from [regex for port number](https://ihateregex.io/expr/port/)

```
((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))
```

Each of these work **independently** to match an IP address and port number just fine.

I combined them

```
(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\:((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))
```

and the result is, for example:

```
256.250.139.193:1234  // bad IP, good port. The RegEx matches "56.250.139.193:1234". Fail. I want it to match nothing
1.1.1.1:65535         // good IP, good port #. The RegEx matches "1.1.1.1:65535". Pass. This is what I want it to do
1.1.1.1:65536         // good IP, bad port, matches "1.1.1.1:". Fail. I want it to match nothing
```

I can't figure out how to combine them to match all or nothing. I tried using repetition and grouping and it either didn't change what is matched or broke the RegEx entirely

Comment: You don't need to escape `:`

Comment: True, not a requirement, but escaping the colon make my intent clear for the next guy looking at my RegEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put word boundaries around the pattern.

Also, you had an error in your pattern for the port number. `[0-5]{0,5}` should be `[0-5]{1,5}`, otherwise it matches an empty port number.

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{1,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ZAKSOx/4)

Comment: Including anchors will cause a fail in the case where a line has text other than an IP and port #. for example: "FOO 1.1.1.1:1 BAR". In the case of "FOO 1.1.1.1:1 BAR", I want the RegEx to match "1.1.1.1:1"

Comment: Use word boundaries instead of anchors. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Adding the word boundary regex `\b` to the front and back of my regex works for the case where I have an invalid IP address:valid port #, (e.g., it won't match any part of  256.250.139.193:1234 ) but if I have a valid IP address:invalid port number, it still matches the IP address part, i.e. it matches the "1.1.1.1:" portion of "1.1.1.1:65536"

Comment: That's what I fixed when I changed `{0,5}` to `{1,5}`. Didn't you see that in the updated answer?

Comment: My apologies!!  I completely missed the "Also, you had an error in your pattern" portion of your original comment. I'm too old for small screen fonts AND it's Monday :-). Your current answer does the trick. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

One reliable and readable way, using a specific Perl parser [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common):

```
perl -MRegexp::Common -lne '
    my ($ip, $port) = /^($RE{net}{IPv4}):(\d+)$/;
    print "$ip:$port" if defined $ip and defined $port and $port  < 65536
' file
```

Comment: Where is the port number in that? And where are the anchors so it won't match a substring of the line?

Comment: Added anchors and port number handling

Comment: `\d+` will match a number larger than `65535`

Comment: A valid port # is in the range 0..65535. The portion of the RegEx I'm using for this is `((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))`. By itself, it works fine to match a valid port number

Comment: Also, sorry, my bad for not specifying - I'm implementing this in a C# app. I updated my question. Using Perl would be a pain.

Comment: Added a test on port < 65536